# How can you set up a default drawing directory in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad, cad

How can you set up a default drawing directory in AutoCAD?

I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can you set up a default drawing directory in AutoCAD?

Do the following:

> - Right-click the AutoCAD shortcut icon located on the desktop and click Properties.
>
>   - If the shortcut icon is located in the Windows taskbar, the Properties can be accessed by right-clicking on it followed by another
>     right click on the visible AutoCAD name/pictogram.
> - In the Start in field, enter the desired folder path (example: "C:\Drawings"). Note that double quotes should be used around the
>   folder path.
> - Launch AutoCAD.
> - Type REMEMBERFOLDERS in the command line.
> - Enter 0 to turn it off.
>
> AutoCAD will now use C:\Drawings as a default folder for SAVE and OPEN
> operations as long as the modified shortcut is used to start it. Note
> that AutoCAD still remembers the last-used folder. Browsing to a
> different folder at any time will cause AutoCAD to go back to that
> same folder the next time. Exiting and restarting AutoCAD will revert
> the default path back to what was specified in the 'Start in' property
> of the shortcut.

Source: [How to set a default SAVE/OPEN folder location for drawings in AutoCAD](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-set-a-default-SAVE-OPEN-folder.html)